# Is posible to retrieve info from Microsoft Teams directly?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to retrieve, with c#, info like chats names or chat participants, but all the documentation I can found if about using bots to retrieve this info, so, is possible access to the teams client  with some type of connector to retrieve this info directly?
Tnx in advance.

Just for clarify, I don't want to create Teams app, has to be 100% client, listening the possible Teams events to retrieve info.

Comment: Google `Microsoft Teams Api`. Here is a direct link to Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet

Comment: I don't understand why this question gets negative views. A very good question actually from a new SO user (thank you  Svalyn).  Especially, when the answer from the  MS Teams Platform Architect  has a link to a different API, the Microsoft Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't creating a Teams app, here's what's supported today, with more coming all the time: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/teams_api_overview.

Comment: A different question from me. Is there a way, today, to get notifications in an external application about real-time call control events (ring,accept,hangup, callerID)? maybe using a bot or connector or Graph API?